# CodeIgniter: How can I populate a new database with cloned website source files?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-migration

I have been sent a copy of the files of a Code Igniter website. It is the files on the live website simply zipped up and sent over.

I have cloned it on my machine and connected it to an empty MySQL database. I am used to being able to run some code that will then populate the database with the correct tables. I can't work out how to do this with this site.

I have looked at the migration section of the CodeIgniter documentation and searched for solutions on this topic on Google and Stack Overflow.

The error I get is:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'test.users' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `deleted` != 1

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testserver/models/user_model.php

Line Number: 242
```

Would I need a copy of the current database from the live site? Is there a way I can run a script to create the database tables?

I have never used CodeIgniter. So far I have seen I need to do this in migration.php.

```
$config['migration_enabled'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Did the author create any migration files for you to use?

Comment: No, I can't find any migration files where I would expect them to be from what I read in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, so you will need to ask the author to send you the database schema as well.

Comment: I have found what looks to be an old database schema. I ran it. It is clear from errors being returned that the database structure has subsequently been changed. I will need to add the extra columns as it asks for them. I found it in [site_root]/sql directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help MonkeyZeus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what the error message basically tells you is that you need a database called 'test' with a table called 'users' (test.users)

You should check if any migrations has been written in /application/migrations you should be able to run them by pointing your browser at example.com/index.php/migrate. Given that you've setup your database config.

Comment: There is no migrations folder in the application or any other folder. I searched the directory of everything I have been sent and there are no PDF backups. I tried http://localhost:8888/testserver/index.php/migrate and it returned a 404 error.

Comment: I guess you'll need to recreate the database from looking at the models then.

Comment: I can hopefully get a dump of the database but that will have to wait till after the weekend.